# Can't disable Macbook Pro M1 Trackpad Force click by editing .GlobalPreferences.plist

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode, trackpad, plist

I'm learning how to make a dotfiles backup/restore system for my Macbook Pro M1 (on Monterey 12.7). I was trying to run some:

```
defaults write
```

commands to see how it will affect the OS. Some of the commands make no change when applied. For example this one:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.forceClick -bool false
```

When open `.GlobalPreferences.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences/` with Xcode, I can see that `com.apple.trackpad.forceClick` key value was successfully registered as `false`. However the "Force Click and haptic feedback" check box in System Preferences/Trackpad/ was still checked ?

Can someone help me to understand this behavior. Thank you !

I've done the following steps:

1. Set full disk access for Iterm2
2. Make sure System Preference is closed
3. Run `defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.forceClick -bool false`
4. Using Xcode to view `.GlobalPreferences.plist` and make sure is was changed
5. Restart computer

Comment: Rough guess: maybe haptic feedback is on?

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you please elaborate further ?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct key and plist? If you change the setting in the UI, which plist has had its modification date changed?

Comment: @benwiggy Thank you, this is a great tip to find the next .plist and key that I need to change.

Comment: @m1do Maybe you have disabled Force Touch by running the command you give in the question but perhaps Haptic Feedback is still on and it makes the System Setting option still show as ticked? Apparently you have found an answer and that wasn't the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking at the wrong .plist and key from the beginning. I was able to solve this following suggestion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/179vxc6/comment/k5911y8/?context=3) by user padamdam

Disable - ForceTouch and Haptic Feedback

```
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad ForceSuppressed -bool true
```

Restart is required.